# Why isn't my view input data passed to my controller like the rest of the inputs?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this view that passes back an `IEnumerable<WeeklyTarget>` object to the controller. All of my inputs successfully bind to the model that gets sent to the controller action except for one. This input is a little different than the rest, when a user selects a button on the page I make an ajax call to replace the original input of type display to a number editor for this property. Here's the form/view before the ajax call:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEdit", "WeeklyTarget", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            // this first hidden input sets the index for each item in Model      
            @Html.Hidden("weeklytargets.Index", item.WeeklyTargetId)

            // this hidden input binds perfectly, along with the other next two
            @Html.Hidden("weeklytargets[" + item.WeeklyTargetId + "].WeeklyTargetId", item.WeeklyTargetId)
            <td>
                // this binds fine also
                @Html.Hidden("weeklytargets[" + item.WeeklyTargetId + "].UserId", item.UserId)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                // and lastly, this binds fine as well
                @Html.Hidden("weeklytargets[" + item.WeeklyTargetId + "].WeekId", item.WeekId)
                @item.Weekly.WeekBeginning.ToShortDateString()  -  @item.Weekly.WeekEnding.ToShortDateString()
            </td>
            <td id="hoursEdit-@item.WeeklyTargetId">
                // this display here is replaced with a different line of razor code
                // when the user selects edit, the updated code is after the jump
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)
            </td>
            <td>
                // this edit button makes an ajax call to replace the display above
                @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Index", "WeeklyTarget",
                    new {id = item.WeeklyTargetId},
                    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "hoursEdit-"+@item.WeeklyTargetId, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { @class = "edit-button", @id = item.WeeklyTargetId }) |                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

So when that Edit button makes the ajax call, it replaces the `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hours)` with this line of code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => item.Hours, null, "weeklytargets[" + Model.WeeklyTargetId + "].Hours")
```

Now in the chrome debugger, I've double checked what these input's names evaluate to so that they bind correctly to my model, they are as follows:

```
name="weeklytargets[X].WeeklyTargetId"
name="weeklytargets[X].UserId"
name="weeklytargets[X].WeekId"
name="weeklytargets[X].Hours"
```

That last one for 'Hours' is the only one that shows up as null in the controller's parameter for the weeklytargets object, why is this? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this field Hours declared in the model class?

Comment: `public Nullable<int> Hours { get; set; }`